# Quanta of fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, field-theory

I just heard the term quanta of a field. I’m trying to understand it. Does it mean that field starts acting in a way that is measurable or singularly measurable? Almost as if the “density” or some other attribute of the field makes it act like a “particle”?

Comment: This might help, though it is about something slightly different. [The Higgs Field, explained - Don Lincoln](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joTKd5j3mzk)

Comment: Are you already familiar with a single quantum harmonic oscillator? That's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quanta of fields is in the vocabulary of Quantum Field Theory( QFT). QFT is a mathematical theory where a differential operator operates on a field, creating a "quantum" of that field.The "quantum" and the "field" are two different mathematical functions.

For example take the QFT of elementary particle physics. The [Standard Model (SM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) has a table with axiomatically  defined elementary particles, which have the masses and quantum numbers in the table, and are point particles . This  QFT axiomatically assumes that each particle in the table is a field extending all over space time. Mathematically this field is represented by the plane wave solution of the given particle, solution to its appropriate equation ( Dirac for electrons...) On these fields differential creation and annihilation operators operate, creating or annihilating a particle. The formalism leads to [Feynman diagrams](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) that allow the calculation of the interaction of particles, because the diagram represents pictorially  a term in the solution of the scattering equation.

Thus fields and particles have a different mathematical representation.