# Waves in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, waves, klein-gordon-equation

There are two sources of 'waviness" in quantum field theory: waves in the underlying classical field, and the Schrodinger equation. I'm learning QFT using the notes by David Tong (I believe they are pretty standard), and having hard time reconciling the two notions even in the example of the free scalar field.

It is mentioned that quantum states in this context are functions $\Phi:\{\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}\} \to \mathbb{C}$ analogous to wave functions in classical QM. Or perhaps they should be $\Phi_t:\{\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}\} \to \mathbb{C}$, as to have the Schrodinger picture going. I assume the latter and drop the subscript $t$.

Then quantum fields are defined as fields of operators acting on the states, in particular: $\hat \phi (\vec x)$ and $\hat \pi (\vec x)$ (I added the hats for clarity).

**What is $\hat \phi (\vec x)\Phi$ equal to?** Is it defined by $(\hat \phi (\vec x)\Phi)(\phi)=\phi(\vec x) \Phi(\phi)$ for a field configuration $\phi$?

Then creation/annihilation ($\hat a_{\vec p},\hat a_{\vec p}^\dagger$) operators are used to find eigenstates of the Hamiltonian operator in terms of $|0\rangle$. In particular, the one-particle eigenstate of the Hamiltonian with momentum $\vec p$ is $|\vec p\rangle = \hat a_{\vec p}^\dagger|0\rangle$.

I saw the following description of $|\vec p\rangle$ as a wave function. Let $\phi_{A, \vec p}$ be the classical plane wave at time $t=0$ in the direction of $\vec p$ with frequency proportional to $|\vec p|$ and amplitude $A$. Then $|\vec p\rangle$ ($\phi_{A, \vec p}$) as a function of $A$ is the same as the $n=1$ solution of the simple harmonic oscillator as a function of $\ x$.

**Is $|\vec p\rangle$ equal to zero on any other field configuration?**
What about the values of $|\vec p\rangle$ on shifted $\phi_{A, \vec p}$? (i.e. for the same wave at later times as a classical wave). Perhaps $|\vec p\rangle$ has values $e^{i s}$ (multiplied by the same function of $A$) for the shifted by $s$ wave and zero for anything else?

**What about $|\vec p\rangle_t$?** I want to say that the unitary transformation $e^{-i \hat H t \over \hbar}$ "propagates" the classical wave by shifting the probability amplitude to the shifted $\phi_{A, \vec p}$ to classically later times, but not at all sure if that's true.
Can something like that be said in general, or at least for Hamiltonian eigenstates? That is, can the Schrodinger equation "propagate" quantum states in this classical sense? More generally, what about wave packets composed of different momenta?

**What is $|0\rangle$ as a wave function?**

Comment: Maybe the answers here will help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208615/

Comment: @annav no, that question seems to be about relating QFT to the "particle" wave function, while I'm trying to understand QFT Schrodinger equation with the underlying classical field equations.

Comment: motl has shown here  how classical electromagnetic waves arise from quantum field theory https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html

Comment: @annav but that post if from point of view of "particle" wave functions $\phi_1 \otimes \phi_2 \otimes \phi_3 \otimes ...$, while I want to understand wave functions on field configurations.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are trrying the impossible due to the enormity of statistics.Classical fields  emerge from quantum mechanics underlying variables . Waves on classical fields involve an enormous number of variables of quantum ones. It is like saying "write the sea waves as a function of the individual molecules from  which they emerge"

Comment: " "particle" wave functions ". No, it is normal quantum field theory, operators operating on particle fields , i.e. photon fields in this case , which mathematically are the plane wave solutions ( no potential) of the quantized maxwell equations http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002?ln=en

Comment: see this answer of mine https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/626938/quanta-of-fields/626956#626956 about QFT used in particle physics

Comment: @annav I'm not claiming it's not normal quantum field theory. I'm merely saying that wave functions in the formulations you linked take coordinates of a collection of particles and produce a complex number, while I'm interested in the formulation of QFT where a wave functions takes classical field configuration and produces a complex number. Most of my questions are really concrete, I even have a partial answer in the question text, but it's not complete and without derivation.

Comment: The only long range quantum field theory is the one used for superconductivity, and it is not  structured the way you think , but it does predict correctly the behavior of classical fields in superconducting material. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity (there is also superfluidity